# Slowlying varying function with no limit at infinity: using Karamata representation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, slowly-varying-functions

I want to find a slowly varying function that has no limit at infinity, and write down its Karamata's representation .

That is, I want to find $L: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ with the $\lim_{x \to \infty} L(x)$ not existing, and I want to write down $L(x) = c(x) \exp(\int^x_1 \epsilon(t) t^{-1} dt$ where $c, \epsilon \colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ with $c(x) \to c \in (0,\infty)$ as $x \to \infty$, and $\epsilon(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

The definition I am using is from the book Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes.

[image]

[image]

I have read that $\sin \ln \ln x+2$ fits the bill, but I do not know its Karamata's representation.

I also thought

$L(x) = \exp(\sin \ln \ln x) = \exp(\int^x_e \frac{\cos \ln \ln t}{t \ln t} dt$) would work but $\frac{\cos \ln \ln t}{\ln t}$ is not strictly positive so it does not fit the requirement that $\epsilon(t)$ is strictly positive.

So my question is, what slowly varying function has no limit at infinity, and what is its Karamata's representation?

Comment: @Gonçalo excluding the case of $\lim_{x \to \infty} L(x)$ since $\ln \ln (e+x)$ is slowly varying and it tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Wikipedia has no restriction of $\epsilon(t)$ being strictly positive, and I suspect that might be correct since I don't see how it follows from the proof in the book that $\epsilon(t)$ is strictly positive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function